# Rows sorting changes after updating a column not related to sorting at all

Tags: postgresql

Have a ORM generated SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "games" WHERE "competition_id" IN
(SELECT "id" FROM "competitions" WHERE "id"  IN (1,2,3))
ORDER BY "date" LIMIT 10
```

It is displaying rows 1 to 10.

However after:

```
UPDATE "games" SET "season_id"=2
```

same `SELECT` returns rows like 1,2,3 ... 11, 12 instead of 1,2,3 ... 9, 10

Yes, returned rows are still 10, but last ones are always replaced with ones after 10...

Comment: why shouldn't it? your update query is forcing ALL games(or whatever) to be part of season 2. so if your games with values 11,12 were (say) season 4, now they'll be part of season 2.

Comment: ok, but i'm ordering by "date"!

Comment: Is there any triggers? can you show more informations about tables relation ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not modify the subquery to be just `(1,2,3)` instead of a SELECT statement that results in the same thing?

Comment: as i said, it is a ORM generated SQL, i'm using db via Ruby DataMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` doesn't guarantee which rows will be returned if multiple matching results exist within the `ORDER BY` scope.  So if you have more than 10 rows with the same `date`, or if most have different dates but it so happens that the 9th, 10th, 11th and 12th rows have the same `date`, you aren't guaranteed to get consistent results for which will be returned for the 9th and 10th slots.  PostgreSQL will choose these at its own discretion - which will often change when records are updated.

Try adding `id` to the ORDER BY list to fix this.

Comment: i need them strongly ordered by "date"

Comment: @slivu, do rows 9, 10, 11, and 12 have the same `date` value?

Comment: Then ORDER BY `date` won't do anything for you. They are already in 'order' :)  Try expanding the ORDER BY to include `id`.

Comment: well, i meant all 10 have same date, but there are many other rows with different date, that's why i want to sort by date and keep that order after update. imagine you have a page with 10 items on it and after editing some data the page displays another items, even if updated data is not used in `ORDER BY`

Comment: @slivu: Understood, this is why I proposed changing the ORDER BY list to - `date, id` rather than just `date`.  This will guarantee that for multiple items with the same `date` they will always be returned in the same order since `id` is always unique.  For items with different `date` values the `id` is ignored and it is sorted by `date`.

Comment: doh, sure, that's the logical solution, how could it i oversee it, shame on me...